# Using Dexie.js from content script of a WebExtension

Tags: indexeddb, firefox-addon-webextensions, dexie

I'm trying to use Dexie.js from a content script inside my Firefox extension but it throws an error when I try to open the database.

Dexie.js works great from a background script but I'm trying to move it to a content script so I can integrate it with React to take advantage of data-binding.

My current assumption is I have an issue with CORS, but since dexie.js and content_script.js are both content scripts I would think they're both running in the same context?

**Manifest**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Content Script Dexie",
    "description": "Example showing how to use Dexie.js from a content script",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": [
                "https://*.stackoverflow.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "dexie.js",
                "content_script.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
let db = new Dexie("test_db");
db.version(1).stores({ table: 'column1, column2' })
db.open().then(() => {
    console.log("Database is open, adding some data")
    db.table.add({ column1: 12345, column2: 54321 })
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error("Database failed to open: " + err.message)
    console.error("Stack: " + err.stack)
})
```

**Error message**

> Database failed to open: "then" is read-only

```
switchToZone@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:1154:13
usePSD@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:1191:25
newScope@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:1092:24
vip@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:3698:16
dexieOpen/<@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:3801:41
nativeAwaitCompatibleWrap/<@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:1204:27
callListener@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:926:23
endMicroTickScope@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:998:29
physicalTick@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:981:34
promise callback*schedulePhysicalTick<@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:583:45
asap@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:600:13
propagateToListener@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:919:13
propagateAllListeners@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:896:32
executePromiseTask/<@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:856:42
promise callback*resolve/<@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:764:27
executePromiseTask@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:840:15
DexiePromise@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:654:27
resolve@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:763:24
race/</<@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:774:67
race/<@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:774:24
executePromiseTask@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:840:15
DexiePromise@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:654:27
race@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:773:20
dexieOpen@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:3736:29
Dexie.prototype.open@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/dexie.js:4736:20
@moz-extension://e3e29ba0-87d2-4af2-9671-b550c1acc42a/content_script.js:3:4
```

Comment: IndexedDB of the extension won't be available in the content script. Use messaging to pass the data. You can write a Proxy to handle it transparently, examples: [one](/a/55201393), [two](/a/60359888).

Comment: I currently have it setup so that the background script returns some JSON representation of the database, but I was looking to have a React component access the DB directly as described here: https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/React

Comment: See if dexie supports adding custom adaptors so you'll use messaging to relay the individual commands to the background script.